# I can't use Waiters in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I made a simple program through golang and deploy using Serverless Framework.

And I got to using [Waiters](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/making-requests/#using-waiters).

The example in the link above is DynamoDB, but I used it for RDS.

```
err := svc.WaitUntilDBInstanceDeleted(&rds.DescribeDBInstancesInput{
    DBInstanceIdentifier: aws.String(InstanceName),
})
```

But when I look at the log through cloudwatch, Waiters not executed.

The functions before and after the Waiters are executed immediately and an error occurs.

Can't I use Waiters in Lambda?

Comment: Did the Lambda function time out? CloudWatch Logs would indicate this. BTW I suspect that the deletion of an RDS instance is a time-consuming operation and not something that you would typically wait for in a short-duration Lambda function.

Comment: I know that Lambda's timeout is 15 minutes. When I tested it on localhost, it didn't take that long, so I deploy to the Lambda. And in localhost, the time of the function executed before and after the Waiter was different, but in CloudWatch, it was immediately executed.